# Unhandled error in Deferred

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

It seems it is inner twisted error... It appears at regular intervals, and actually everything keep work fine, but may be it is my mistake? A code is pretty big, so I [pasted it there](http://pastebin.com/tHEWxuJn), and the error:

```
07:51:32 startLive
07:51:34 time is off
07:51:34 again
07:51:36 time is off
07:51:36 again
07:51:38 time is off
07:51:38 again
07:51:40 time is off
07:51:40 again
07:51:42 time is off
07:51:42 again
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.defer.CancelledError: 
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.defer.CancelledError: 
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.defer.CancelledError: 
07:51:44 time is off
07:51:44 again
07:51:46 time is off
07:51:46 again
07:51:48 time is off
07:51:48 again
```

Comment: Please cut your code down to a small, self-contained example, and include it in your question, not a pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a single call to `Deferred.addErrback` anywhere in the code you pasted (and please listen to Glyph and don't paste code on external sites).

You should read [the section of the Deferred documentation on errbacks](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto4).

Comment: thanks... I'll do it. the code is just too big to post it there.

Comment: You can usually shorten it will retaining the part that's relevant to the question: http://sscce.org/